# Nest JS - Client validation failed : Path is required

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm posting here because I have been stuck on a problem for few hours now.
I am creating an API using Nest JS 8 and MongoDB, and I test it using Postman. When I want to execute a POST request  (http://localhost:3000?nom=Antoine) to insert an object in my database, I have an error (500 : Internal server error) message that says "Client validation failed: nom: Path 'nom' is required (nom is the name of my object's property).

I've wandered every topic about this kind of issue, tried to upgrade my version of Nest, to use a middleware, to make sure the right version of every depedency was installed.

I don't want to remove the "required: true" property because i think it is necessary. I tried to set it to "false", which enabled me to insert the object in the database but without my property 'nom' (name in french).

If you guys have any help, here's my schema :

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type ClientDocument = Client & Document;

@Schema()
export class Client {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  nom: string;
}

export const ClientSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Client);
```

And here is my controller :

```
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientService } from './client.service';
import { ClientDto } from './dto/client.dto';
import { CreateClientDto } from './dto/create-client.dto';
import { UpdateClientDto } from './dto/update-client.dto';

@Controller('/client')
export class ClientController {
    constructor(private readonly clientService: ClientService) {}

    @Get()
    async index(){
        return await this.clientService.findAll();
    }

    @Get(':id')
    async find(@Param('id') id: string) {
        return await this.clientService.findOne(id);
    }

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() createClientDto: CreateClientDto) {
        console.log(createClientDto);
        return await this.clientService.create(createClientDto);
    }

    @Put(':id')
    async update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateClientDto: ClientDto) {
        return await this.clientService.update(id, updateClientDto);
    }

    @Delete(':id')
    async delete(@Param('id') id: string) {
        return await this.clientService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: please edit your question to add the request you're sending from postman.

Comment: What do you get out of `console.log(createClientDto);`?

Comment: I get : { « nom »: « Antoine » } which seems correct to me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (i still don't know why it works this way tho).

In my client.service.ts, i updated the create function from this :

```
async create(createClientDto: CreateClientDto): Promise<Client> {
        return await new this.model({createClientDto}).save();
    }
```

To this

```
async create(createClientDto: CreateClientDto): Promise<Client> {
    return await new this.model({
      ...createClientDto,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    }).save();
  }
```

Thanks for taking the time to answer, I hope this will help